# loop in database design

Tags: sql, database, database-design

We have some tables that has relation together in following design:

```
T1 --> T2 --> T3 --> T4 --> T1
```

[image]
So I think we have circular relation in our design.
I want to know, is it OK in database design?

Comment: The world is what it is.  If you provide the entities and relationships, then someone could comment on your actual design.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: If it's Ok, What is loop in database design?